# Swift UI 2.0: How can to set up this Notification?

Tags: notifications, swiftui, ios14

First of all, I have never used notifications in an app.  I have done tutorials but the whole thing confuses me.

I have created a SwiftUI file called Notify.swift.  I want the user to be able to set a time for a notification to alert them to perform a task at a specified time, like in this image:

[image: notify.swift file image]

Where you see the time in the image, I have created a DatePicker to pick a time for the notification:

```
VStack {
    Button(action: {}) {
        HStack {
             DatePicker("   Select a time ....", 
                 selection: $wakeup, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                 .font(.title2)
                 .accentColor(Color(.white))
        }
    }.background(Color(.black))
}
.frame(width: .infinity, height: 40, alignment: .center)
.padding()
```

When the user clicks on the Create Button to set the notification, it should set the notification at that particular time (all the time, unless changed).  This is what I need to happen but don't know how to do it:

If the notification time is set for 8:30am, like in the image, and the user selects CREATE, a notification is set and should be sent to the user to perform whatever task with maybe a sound and a message at that specified time.

I understand that there are different types of notification: local, user, Apple push, etc, but I don't know which type this falls in or how to do it.

Would this be a notification or an alarm?

Comment: you can use local notification for that, and local notification allow you to set a time to trigger the notification.

Comment: @Cod3rMax Do you suggest any tutorials i can check out to do this particular Notification for setting a time to trigger the notification?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local notifications for that. Here I made a function for you to trigger the notification. First off all, check if that time is prior the current time. Then the notification will be tomorrow and we add one day to our Date. You can change title, body as you wish.

Make sure to wrap your DatePicker outside the button, otherwise it will always trigger a notification when you click the DatePicker.

```
func scheduleNotification() -> Void {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Your title"
    content.body = "Your body"
    
    var reminderDate = wakeup
    
    if reminderDate < Date() {
        if let addedValue = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: reminderDate) {
            reminderDate = addedValue
        }
    }

    let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: reminderDate)
                           
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: comps, repeats: false)
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "alertNotificationUnique", content: content, trigger: trigger)

     UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
         if let error = error {
             print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
         }
     }
}
```

Also you need to request permission for Notifications like this:

```
func requestPush() -> Void {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
        if success {
            print("All set!")
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Here your button:

```
VStack {
    Button(action: {
        scheduleNotification()
    }) {
        Text("Save notification")
    }
     DatePicker("Select a time ....",
         selection: $wakeup, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
         .font(.title2)
         .accentColor(Color(.white))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @daviddev for that.  When you say wrap your DatePicker outside the button, do i change it to be how you show above ? rather than the one i had it?  My DatePicker was in an HStack() inside the button - do i no longer need the HStack()?

Comment: Yes. Currently in your example the DatePicker was part of the content of the Button. If you click the DatePicker, the button triggers the action.

Comment: Yes the DatePicker triggers the picker but the CREATE button below at bottom of page should be used to trigger the notification. - No?

Comment: I did as you have here and when i select save notifications, nothing happens on the time of the notification.

Comment: You first have to request for notifications and the user allowed it. I added the code above

Comment: where do i call the new function? requestPush() ??  cause nothing happened

Comment: Before calling scheduleNotification().. you can onAppear() or inside your button

Comment: inside button before calling scheduleNotification?

Comment: i did this: Button(action: {
                    requestPush()
                        scheduleNotification()
                    }) {
No notification received

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225869/discussion-between-davidev-and-lizg).